# Next.js redirect www to non www

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have been trying to find a workable solution this searching google but can't find anything solid. I am hosting my Next.js application on Vercel.

When I run a seo check it moans about me having the site available on www and non www and says I should pick one and get it to redirect so in my case, if someone types in [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) I would prefer it left of the www.

Since I don't have a htaccess file I can do this in, how would I do it?

Not sure if it matters, but I am using WordPress as my backend aka: Headless Wordpress

Comment: I'd recommend having a read through [Redirecting Domains](https://vercel.com/blog/redirecting-domains).

Comment: @juliomalves thanks for this. But this is from 2019 and when I tried to find this in my vercel account I didn't see it. I don't know if it might because I am just pointing the A record to vercel and not the nameservers ?

Comment: I want to redirect from non-www to www, please help me

Comment: Did you figure this out? The accepted answer does not work for me. I've tried all sorts of variations aswell. Nothing seems to work...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to use host-based redirects now since Next v10.2. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching.

In next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  redirects: async () => [
    {
      source: '/:path*',
      has: [{ type: 'host', value: 'www.yourdomain.com' }],
      destination: 'https://yourdomain.com/:path*',
      permanent: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I want to redirect from non www to www, please help me

Comment: @haxora, Just change the `has.value` to `yourdomain.com` and add the www to the destination.

Comment: {
            source: '/',
            has: [{ type: 'host', value: 'https://learnbay.co' }],
            destination: 'https://www.learnbay.co/',
            permanent: false
    }  

 **This is my code and i tried all possible way but its not redirecting by default to www** @rvanlaarhoven

Comment: The `destination` should be a valid URL, so: `https://www.learnbay.co`

Comment: I used something similar, because I don't think this would work. You should do in has like this ```has: [{type: 'header', key: 'host', value: 'www.yourdomain.com'}]```

Comment: Is this the correct way to handle making all routes SSL?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily handle permanent redirection in nextjs using the below-mentioned code.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const { req, res } = context;

    if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null) {
        res.writeHead(301, {
            location: "https://" + req.headers.host.replace(/^www./, "") + req.url,
        });
        res.end();
    }

    return { props: {} };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with next@14:

```js
module.exports = {
  redirects: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        has: [{ type: 'header', key: 'host', value: 'www.example.com' }],
        destination: 'https://example.com/:path*',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```